# Is there a way to automatically rollback a snap if the service fails to start?

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

> For the gadget, kernel, and OS snaps, if these fail to start correctly, the snappy system will automatically revert these snaps the next time the device is booted.
>   http://snapcraft.io/docs/core/updates

I want to have similar functionality for my application snap where if the service it provides fails to start, the snap is automatically reverted. Is there a defined mechanism to support this? Does anyone have ideas on how I could implement this myself? I could create a second snap application to manage the "real" snap but I would like to avoid that if I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a mechanism to deal with this. You might find [this article/walkthough](https://kyrofa.com/posts/snap-updates-automatic-rollbacks) helpful. The basic idea (from the article):

> Snapd won't check the health of your snap for you, as it doesn't know
>   enough about your snap to perform a decent health check. However, it's
>   pretty easy to check the health yourself.
>
> Snapd recently gained support for [hooks](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/wiki/hooks), which is a way for snapd to
>   notify individual snaps about various events. There's one hook in
>   particular that supports configuration. It's beyond the scope of this
>   post to walk through configuration itself, but there's something
>   important about this hook that's worth knowing: it runs upon initial
>   install, and it runs when the snap is updated, after the snap's services are started. This makes it a decent
>   place to perform a health check.